# Why triggering click doesn't change tab navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is navigation I would like to control from code

```
<div data-role="page" id="settingsPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" class="ui-btn-active">Tab One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two">Tab Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#three">Tab Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            <div id="two" class="ui-body-d ui-content">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div id="three" class="ui-body-d ui-content">cccccccccccc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I try to switch to second tab:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    $("#two").trigger("click");

}, 3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v7z6fj05/7/)

Nothing happens. How to switch?

Comment: You have to trigger on link not div

Comment: ah, you are absolutely right!

Comment: @NicolasPerraut you should change your comment to an answer so Pablo can accept it as "the answer". Cheers

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active straight-forward solution.

Comment: @Omar: `active` is changing content, but doesn't change highlighted item in navbar: http://jsfiddle.net/v7z6fj05/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("li>a[href='#two']").trigger("click");
}, 3000);
```

You can get More information about [tag selector([])](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [child selector (>)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) from provide links.

Comment: could you please give a link where `>` and `[]` selector syntax is described?